# Using ValidationGroup and Client-Side Validation with ASP.NET Custom Server Control

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, custom-server-controls, clientscriptmanager

I am creating a custom server control to generate button elements with specific markup and JavaScript handlers for my Web Forms application. They are, of course, able to cause postbacks, so I would like them to function with any of ASP's validation controls for form validation, especially the client-side framework.

This button server control supports an `OnClientClick` property to emit an `onclick` attribute in the button tag with the code provided (primarily used for a simple confirmation reprompt when a user clicks a delete button for a list view or similar), so using the `asp:Button` control's method of emitting the validation script as an onclick attribute will be pretty ineffectual. As a matter of fact, specifying both `OnClientClick` and `ValidationGroup` attributes on a standard `asp:Button` turns out pretty badly. Here's a painfully obvious example of why that's not working out of the box:

**Page Markup**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveAsp" ValidationGroup="vgMyValidationGroup" OnClientClick="return true;" runat="server" />
```

**Rendered Markup**

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cphBodyContent$lvMyList$ctrl0$btnSaveAsp" value="Save"  id="cphBodyContent_lvUsers_btnSaveAsp_0"
    onclick='return true; WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$cphBodyContent$lvMyList$ctrl0$btnSaveAsp", "", true, "vgMyValidationGroup", "", false, false))'>
```

Here is the existing non-working code for wiring up the control with validation. I was unable to find much documentation on how best to accomplish this with a method aside from emitting a similar `onclick` attribute. I thought my call to `Page.ClientSCript.RegisterForEventValidation` in the overridden `AddAttributesToRender` method would wire up the client-side validation, but that does not appear to be functioning as I assumed. If necessary, jQuery is available for use in binding additional handling to the button's click event:

**Custom Server Button Control**

```
<ToolboxData("<{0}:Button runat=server></{0}:Button>")> _
<ParseChildren(False)> _
<PersistChildren(True)> _
Public Class Button
    Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl
    Implements IPostBackDataHandler

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button)
    End Sub

    <Category("Behavior")> _
    <DefaultValue("")> _
    Public Overridable Property PostBackUrl As String
        Get
            Return If(ViewState("PostBackUrl"), String.Empty)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            ViewState("PostBackUrl") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Validation")> _
    <DefaultValue(True)> _
    Public Overridable Property CausesValidation As Boolean
        Get
            Return If(ViewState("CausesValidation"), True)
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            ViewState("CausesValidation") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Validation")> _
    <DefaultValue("")> _
    Public Overridable Property ValidationGroup As String
        Get
            Return If(ViewState("ValidationGroup"), String.Empty)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            ViewState("ValidationGroup") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Category("Behavior")> _
    <DefaultValue("")> _
    <Description("Client-side script to be run when the button is clicked.")> _
    Public Property OnClientClick As String
        Get
            Return If(ViewState("OnClientClick"), String.Empty)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            ViewState("OnClientClick") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub AddAttributesToRender(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        MyBase.AddAttributesToRender(writer)

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(OnClientClick) Then
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, OnClientClick)
        End If

        Dim postBackOptions = GetPostBackOptions()

        If postBackOptions.TargetControl Is Me Then
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, ClientID)
        End If

        If Page IsNot Nothing Then
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(postBackOptions)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Function GetPostBackOptions() As PostBackOptions
        Dim options As New PostBackOptions(Me) With {
            .ClientSubmit = False
        }

        If Page IsNot Nothing Then
            If CausesValidation AndAlso (Page.GetValidators(ValidationGroup).Count > 0) Then
                options.PerformValidation = True
                options.ValidationGroup = ValidationGroup
            End If

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(PostBackUrl) Then
                options.ActionUrl = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(ResolveClientUrl(PostBackUrl))
            End If
        End If

        Return options
    End Function
End Class
```

Presently, this code does not function with an `asp:CompareValidator` in the same `ValidationGroup` to determine if two password reset fields are equal before posting back to the server, nor does validation occur once the request gets to the server side.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what `OnClientClick` would realistically be set to (instead of just `return true`)?

Comment: `return confirm("Are you certain you wish to delete this item"?)` or any other reprompt. I've actually figured a way around this and I'll post my solution soon. It involved a little digging through the guts of ASP.NET's postback handling but if I just add the validation as a listener on the click event, things work well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Making `OnClientClick` work with client-side form validation**

Since the `<asp:Button>` control concatenates the value of `OnClientClick` with the form validation script, the easiest way to make them work together is to `return false` when you want to block the form submission, and do nothing if you want the button to validate and submit the form:

```
OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;"
```

However, if you absolutely want to write `return confirm('Are you sure?')`, then you can move the form validation code to an event listener (as you suggest), or you can wrap the `OnClientClick` code like this:

```
writer.AddAttribute(
    HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick,
    "if (!(function() { " + this.OnClientClick + "; return true; })()) return false;" +
    this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(options, false));
```

**Server-side form validation**

You need to implement the `IPostBackEventHandler` interface and call the `Page.Validate` method. The `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation` method is used for event validation (preventing unauthorized or malicious postbacks), not for form validation.

**Sample code (C#)**

Here is the code for a bare-bones custom button control that supports `OnClientClick` and `ValidationGroup`:

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
public class Button : WebControl, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    private static readonly object EventClick = new object();

    public Button()
        : base(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button)
    {
    }

    public bool CausesValidation
    {
        get { return ((bool?)this.ViewState["CausesValidation"]) ?? true; }
        set { this.ViewState["CausesValidation"] = value; }
    }

    public string ValidationGroup
    {
        get { return (string)this.ViewState["ValidationGroup"] ?? ""; }
        set { this.ViewState["ValidationGroup"] = value; }
    }

    public string OnClientClick
    {
        get { return (string)this.ViewState["OnClientClick"] ?? ""; }
        set { this.ViewState["OnClientClick"] = value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler Click
    {
        add { this.Events.AddHandler(EventClick, value); }
        remove { this.Events.RemoveHandler(EventClick, value); }
    }

    protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, this.UniqueID);

        if (this.Page != null && this.Enabled)
        {
            PostBackOptions options = this.GetPostBackOptions();
            writer.AddAttribute(
                HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick,
                this.OnClientClick + this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(options, false));
        }
    }

    protected virtual PostBackOptions GetPostBackOptions()
    {
        PostBackOptions options = new PostBackOptions(this) { ClientSubmit = false };

        if (this.Page != null)
        {
            if (this.CausesValidation && this.Page.GetValidators(this.ValidationGroup).Count > 0)
            {
                options.PerformValidation = true;
                options.ValidationGroup = this.ValidationGroup;
            }
        }

        return options;
    }

    protected virtual void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)this.Events[EventClick];

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    void IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        if (this.CausesValidation)
        {
            this.Page.Validate(this.ValidationGroup);
        }

        this.OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the consideration in producing an answer. I'd prefer to do the validation client-side regardless of the user response, which is why I wasn't too keen on concatenation. Your answer gives me a good look at causing server-side validation, so I appreciate that. I'd forgotten to move the validation into my `RaisePostBackEvent` handler after moving the button from implementing `IPostBackDataHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at .NET framework Button implementation. Especially AddAttributesToRender method. You can then modify the code to make it works the way you want:

```
public class Button : WebControl, IButtonControl, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    private readonly static object EventClick;

    private readonly static object EventCommand;

    [WebSysDescription("Button_CausesValidation")]
    [WebCategory("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Themeable(false)]
    public bool CausesValidation
    {
        get
        {
            object item = this.ViewState["CausesValidation"];
            if (item == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return (bool)item;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["CausesValidation"] = value;
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Themeable(false)]
    [WebCategory("Behavior")]
    [WebSysDescription("WebControl_CommandArgument")]
    public string CommandArgument
    {
        get
        {
            string item = (string)this.ViewState["CommandArgument"];
            if (item == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["CommandArgument"] = value;
        }
    }

    [Themeable(false)]
    [WebCategory("Behavior")]
    [WebSysDescription("WebControl_CommandName")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string CommandName
    {
        get
        {
            string item = (string)this.ViewState["CommandName"];
            if (item == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["CommandName"] = value;
        }
    }

    [Themeable(false)]
    [WebSysDescription("Button_OnClientClick")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [WebCategory("Behavior")]
    public string OnClientClick
    {
        get
        {
            string item = (string)this.ViewState["OnClientClick"];
            if (item != null)
            {
                return item;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["OnClientClick"] = value;
        }
    }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    [WebCategory("Behavior")]
    [WebSysDescription("Button_PostBackUrl")]
    [Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.UrlEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [Themeable(false)]
    [UrlProperty("*.aspx")]
    public string PostBackUrl
    {
        get
        {
            string item = (string)this.ViewState["PostBackUrl"];
            if (item == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["PostBackUrl"] = value;
        }
    }

    [WebSysDescription("Button_Text")]
    [WebCategory("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            string item = (string)this.ViewState["Text"];
            if (item == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["Text"] = value;
        }
    }

    [WebSysDescription("Button_UseSubmitBehavior")]
    [WebCategory("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Themeable(false)]
    public bool UseSubmitBehavior
    {
        get
        {
            object item = this.ViewState["UseSubmitBehavior"];
            if (item == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return (bool)item;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["UseSubmitBehavior"] = value;
        }
    }

    [WebSysDescription("PostBackControl_ValidationGroup")]
    [WebCategory("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Themeable(false)]
    public string ValidationGroup
    {
        get
        {
            string item = (string)this.ViewState["ValidationGroup"];
            if (item == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["ValidationGroup"] = value;
        }
    }

    static Button()
    {
        Button.EventClick = new object();
        Button.EventCommand = new object();
    }

    public Button() : base(47)
    {
    }

    protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        bool useSubmitBehavior = this.UseSubmitBehavior;
        if (this.Page != null)
        {
            this.Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(this);
        }
        if (!useSubmitBehavior)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "button");
        }
        else
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "submit");
        }
        PostBackOptions postBackOptions = this.GetPostBackOptions();
        string uniqueID = this.UniqueID;
        if (uniqueID != null && (postBackOptions == null || postBackOptions.TargetControl == this))
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, uniqueID);
        }
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, this.Text);
        bool isEnabled = base.IsEnabled;
        string empty = string.Empty;
        if (isEnabled)
        {
            empty = Util.EnsureEndWithSemiColon(this.OnClientClick);
            if (base.HasAttributes)
            {
                string item = base.Attributes["onclick"];
                if (item != null)
                {
                    empty = string.Concat(empty, Util.EnsureEndWithSemiColon(item));
                    base.Attributes.Remove("onclick");
                }
            }
            if (this.Page != null)
            {
                string postBackEventReference = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(postBackOptions, false);
                if (postBackEventReference != null)
                {
                    empty = Util.MergeScript(empty, postBackEventReference);
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.Page != null)
        {
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(postBackOptions);
        }
        if (empty.Length > 0)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, empty);
            if (base.EnableLegacyRendering)
            {
                writer.AddAttribute("language", "javascript", false);
            }
        }
        if (this.Enabled && !isEnabled)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Disabled, "disabled");
        }
        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
    }

    protected virtual PostBackOptions GetPostBackOptions()
    {
        PostBackOptions postBackOption = new PostBackOptions(this, string.Empty);
        postBackOption.ClientSubmit = false;
        if (this.Page != null)
        {
            if (this.CausesValidation && this.Page.GetValidators(this.ValidationGroup).Count > 0)
            {
                postBackOption.PerformValidation = true;
                postBackOption.ValidationGroup = this.ValidationGroup;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PostBackUrl))
            {
                postBackOption.ActionUrl = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(this.ResolveClientUrl(this.PostBackUrl));
            }
            postBackOption.ClientSubmit = !this.UseSubmitBehavior;
        }
        return postBackOption;
    }

    protected virtual void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler item = (EventHandler)base.Events[Button.EventClick];
        if (item != null)
        {
            item(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        CommandEventHandler item = (CommandEventHandler)base.Events[Button.EventCommand];
        if (item != null)
        {
            item(this, e);
        }
        base.RaiseBubbleEvent(this, e);
    }

    protected internal override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        if (this.Page != null && base.IsEnabled)
        {
            if ((!this.CausesValidation || this.Page.GetValidators(this.ValidationGroup).Count <= 0) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PostBackUrl))
            {
                if (!this.UseSubmitBehavior)
                {
                    this.Page.RegisterPostBackScript();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.Page.RegisterWebFormsScript();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        base.ValidateEvent(this.UniqueID, eventArgument);
        if (this.CausesValidation)
        {
            this.Page.Validate(this.ValidationGroup);
        }
        this.OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
        this.OnCommand(new CommandEventArgs(this.CommandName, this.CommandArgument));
    }

    protected internal override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
    }

    private void System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        this.RaisePostBackEvent(eventArgument);
    }

    [WebCategory("Action")]
    [WebSysDescription("Button_OnClick")]
    public event EventHandler Click;
    [WebCategory("Action")]
    [WebSysDescription("Button_OnCommand")]
    public event CommandEventHandler Command;
}
```

Comment: I've already demonstrated a scenario in which the default ASP.NET button handling is inadequate in the post above. This implementation already fails to address using OnClientClick together with a validation group.

Answer (score 0):

continuing Bui Cuion what you need is these 2 things in your cs
1:

```
   protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        bool useSubmitBehavior = this.UseSubmitBehavior;
        if (this.Page != null)
        {
            this.Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(this);
        }
        if (useSubmitBehavior)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "submit");
        }
        else
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "button");
        }
        PostBackOptions postBackOptions = this.GetPostBackOptions();
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, this.Text);
        bool isEnabled = base.IsEnabled;
        string firstScript = string.Empty;
        if (isEnabled)
        {
            firstScript = this.EnsureEndWithSemiColon(this.OnClientClick);
            if (base.HasAttributes)
            {
                string strOnClick = base.Attributes["onclick"];
                if (strOnClick != null)
                {
                    firstScript = firstScript + this.EnsureEndWithSemiColon(strOnClick);
                    base.Attributes.Remove("onclick");
                }
            }
            if (!this.AutoPostBack)
            {
                firstScript = this.MergeScript(this.OnClientClick, "return false;");
            }
            if (this.Page != null)
            {
                string postBackEventReference = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(postBackOptions, false);
                if (postBackEventReference != null)
                {
                    firstScript = this.MergeScript(firstScript, postBackEventReference);
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.Page != null)
        {
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(postBackOptions);
        }
        if (firstScript.Length > 0)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, firstScript);
        }
        if (this.Enabled && !isEnabled)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Disabled, "disabled");
        }
        base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
```

and

```
 protected virtual PostBackOptions GetPostBackOptions()
    {
        PostBackOptions options = new PostBackOptions(this, string.Empty);
        options.ClientSubmit = false;
        if (this.Page != null)
        {
            if (this.CausesValidation && (this.Page.GetValidators(this.ValidationGroup).Count > 0))
            {
                options.PerformValidation = true;
                options.ValidationGroup = this.ValidationGroup;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.PostBackUrl))
            {
                options.ActionUrl = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(base.ResolveClientUrl(this.PostBackUrl));
            }
        }
        return options;
    }
```

options.ClientSubmit = false; is the secret